# When i adding these code into my App showing error on kMESImageQuality

Tags: objective-c

UIImage *originalImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

```
NSData  *imageData    = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, kMESImageQuality);
double   factor       = 1.0;
double   adjustment   = 1.0 / sqrt(2.0);  // or use 0.8 or whatever you want
CGSize   size         = originalImage.size;
CGSize   currentSize  = size;
UIImage *currentImage = originalImage;

while (imageData.length >= (1024 * 1024))
{
    factor      *= adjustment;
    currentSize  = CGSizeMake(roundf(size.width * factor), roundf(size.height * factor));
    currentImage = [originalImage resizedImage:currentSize interpolationQuality:kMESImageQuality];
    imageData    = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(currentImage, kMESImageQuality);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not defined 'kMESImageQuality'. Define a value for 'kMESImageQuality'

Comment: here what is the 'kMESImageQuality'..is any framework required for this.

Comment: when i assigned value like kMESImageQuality=0 showing error like (use of undeclared identifier kMESImageQuality).

Comment: UIImageJPEGRepresentation takes two arguments. One is the reference to the image, and the second one is the compression quality. This shouldd be anything between 0-1. Remove kMESImageQuality and try using 1.. or any number between 0 to 1

Comment: When i do like that here i am getting error currentImage = [originalImage resizedImage:currentSize interpolationQuality:kMESImageQuality];

Comment: is there any other way to create thumbnail Image..please advise me

Comment: [originalImage resizedImage:currentSize interpolationQuality:1];  or [originalImage resizedImage:currentSize interpolationQuality:0];